# How to get updated session data on rails using AngularJs without page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm currently working on  integrating devise as an authentication backend with angular as its frontend.

I have faced a problem on when login and logout, the session data will be updated untill the page refresh.

What i will do get session data without page refresh..?

Thanks for your Answers...

**AngularJs Controller :**

```
function UsersCtrl($scope, Session) {"use strict";

$scope.CurrentUser = Session.requestCurrentUser();

$scope.login = function(user) {
    $scope.authError = null;

    Session.login(user.email, user.password)
    .then(function(response) {
        if (!response) {
            $scope.authError = 'Credentials are not valid';
        } else {
            $scope.authError = 'Success!';
        }
    }, function(response) {
        $scope.authError = 'Server offline, please try later';
    });
};

$scope.logout = function() {
   // alert("woow");
    Session.logout();
};

$scope.register = function(user) {
    $scope.authError = null;
    console.log(user);
    Session.register(user.email, user.password, user.confirm_password)
        .then(function(response) {

        }, function(response) {
            var errors = '';
            $.each(response.data.errors, function(index, value) {
                errors += index.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+index.substr(1) + ' ' + value + ''
            });
            $scope.authError = errors;
        });
};
}
```

**AngularJs Session Service:**

```
 angular.module('sessionService', ['ngResource'])
 .factory('Session', function($location, $http, $q) {
    // Redirect to the given url (defaults to '/')
    function redirect(url) {
        url = url || '/';
        $location.path(url);
    }
    var service = {
        login: function(email, password) {

            return $http.post('/users/login', {user: {email: email, password: password} })
                .then(function(response) {
                    service.currentUser = response.data.user;

                    if (service.isAuthenticated()) {                            
                        //$location.path(response.data.redirect);
                        $location.path('/store');
                    }
                });

        },

        logout: function() {
            $http.delete('/sessions').then(function(response) {
                $http.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = response.data.csrfToken;
                service.currentUser = null;
                redirect('/store');
            });
        },

        register: function(email, password, confirm_password) {
            return $http.post('/users', {user: {email: email, password: password, password_confirmation: confirm_password} })
            .then(function(response) {                    
                service.currentUser = response.data;

                if (service.isAuthenticated()) {
                    console.log("authenticated");
                    $location.path('/');
                }
            });
        },
        requestCurrentUser: function() {
            if (service.isAuthenticated()) {
                return $q.when(service.currentUser);
            } else {
                return $http.get('/users').then(function(response) {
                    service.currentUser = response.data.user;
                    return service.currentUser;
                });
            }
        },

        currentUser: null,

        isAuthenticated: function(){
            return !!service.currentUser;
        }
    };
    return service;
    console.log(service);
});
```

Comment: Please try to extract the relevant parts of your code to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

One Thing about building applications like this (restful) is that understanding the the backend as an api and app as a front-end very well.

Then think about a story as such;

In the login screen of your app

Front-end: You Provided the credentials to your backend;

Back-end: Checked and authenticated then It will create a unique hash stored in db (JWT recommended to check expiration in frontend) to your Front-end.

Front-end:Save it in a cookie.
Also place it in your ajax setting header part as "Authorization: {token}"

Front-end: Then send each request with this header to your backend.

Back-end: Always check if the token is present and valid to provide resources.

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/ this link has helped me understand the whole thing and misconceptions in the past.

Answer (score 0):

use  $window.location.reload(); before page redirect.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this could be overriding the devise sessions_controller destroy action and afrer doing `sign_out @current_user` return the session as json